# Ember-bootstrap to trigger modal from javascript

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-bootstrap

From the link [here](http://www.ember-bootstrap.com/#/components/modal) if you scroll down to the example with the button label 'Reopen Modal' They seem to be triggering the modal from javascript. I have tried `Ember.$('.modal).modal('show')` with no luck, and cant seem to figure out a way to trigger it from js.

My goal is, after a user submits a form and it is successfully validated, the modal appears.

**Template**

```
{{#bs-form model=register onSubmit=(action 'submit') novalidate=true as |form|}}
  {{form.element controlType="text" label="Username" placeholder="Username" property="username"}}
  {{form.element controlType="password" label="Password" placeholder="Password" property="password"}}
  {{bs-button defaultText="Submit" type="outline-success" buttonType="submit"}}
{{/bs-form}}

{{#bs-modal-simple open=modal1 title="Modal" renderInPlace=true}}
    This is a Modal.
{{/bs-modal-simple}}
```

**Component**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    submit() {
      Ember.$('.modal').modal('show');
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The modal would be shown by a boolean property.

```
actions: {
    submit() {
      this.set('modal1', true);
    },
  },
```

Comment: Thank you, that did it. I spent some time searching for something just that simple. I appreciate it.